# auto.arima and Arima equations in R

Tags: r, arima, notation

(First of all, sorry if my English isn't perfect) I'm new in R and with ARIMA models, and I am trying to understand the equations under `Arima` or `auto.arima` functions. I see in many websites such as https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html or here, in many questions, that R works with this equation (1−ϕ1B−⋯−ϕpB^p)*(1-B)^d*Yt=c+(1+θ1B+⋯+θqB^q)*εt.

My question is: why has θ(B) polynomial plus (+),instead of minus (-) like ϕ(B) polynomial? Because in scientific papers where ARIMA's theory is explained, they use the equation with minus, I mean, like this: (1−ϕ1B−⋯−ϕpB^p)*(1-B)^d*Yt=c+(1-θ1B-⋯-θqB^q)*εt. I don't know why R changes this equation or what is the explanation under it. I have been looking for this answer, reading many papers and books, but they don't explain so if anyone knows the answer, I will be very pleasant to read it.

Thanks.

Comment: I thought the notation with + for MA part was standard. It makes perfect sense when you express the model as $y_t=...+\varepsilon_t$ which is the usual general way of writing regression and other models.

Comment: @RichardHardy I think both notations are standard. As you say, the + for MA makes all the terms have + on the RHS when $y_t$ is alone on the LHS. On the other hand, the - for MA makes both sides have the same signs when you put the AR polynomial on the left and the MA on the right (as above). I feel like I see both roughly equally. My guess would be that it depends on the field (e.g. probably differs between statistics and signal processing), but I don't know.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, I cannot disagree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rob Hyndman says](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/):

> Note that R reverses the signs of the moving average coefficients compared to the standard parameterization given above.

He does not go into details. I suspect it was originally just an error in R's `arima()`, which Hyndman then just carried over to the `forecast` package, because correcting it would have led to a whole new lot of confusion. But I stress that this is just conjecture on my part.

Comment: Thank you @StephanKolassa for your answer, it is very useful. After reading it, I just hope that even if the notation is reversed, the results will be the same as using other programming languages. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: @sergio003 The results may not be exactly the same (with flipped signs) in other implementations, but it's unlikely to be because of the parametrization; it will be because of differences in the algorithm used to estimate the parameters, of which there are potentially many (e.g. approximations like conditional sum of squares versus MLE with exact diffuse initialization, etc).